# A free text to speech conveter plugin?

Tags: html, text-to-speech

I'm coding a website that involves functionality whereby a user clicks a nice picture of the Union Jack and the content of the page is read aloud to them.

The problem is I'm finding it really impossible to find a free plug in that easily achieves this effect . . .

Is there any way of accomplishing this easily with a free plugin? Or realistically are there only decent paid for solutions?

Comment: What's the use case? The only ones I can think of are accessibility (where users are very likely to have their own screen reader software already) and pronunciation guides (where a computer generated voice would be more than a little suboptimal).

Comment: Accessibility is the case here. I don't necessarily think it's a good idea myself but it's a featured I've been asked to to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [WebAnywhere](http://webanywhere.cs.washington.edu/), which is an open source university project for a screen reader which does not require any special software installed on the client.  Plug-ins can be problematic as many of them are browser specific. If the content is fairly static a better alternative is to just record the content in an audio file and stream it to the users browser. If the content is dynamic there is software you can use on the server that will take text input and create an audio file that you can then stream to the users browser.